# Replace Output buffer after readfile()

Tags: php, image, output, buffer

I have to do multiple output in a file with "image/jpeg" header.

First file i want to show is an image, then my script do other processing functions and at the end i want to output an other image in the same cycle.

See the code below:

```
<?php
header("content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile(realpath("mypath/default.jpg")); // this output my first image directly
// many other functions 
echo $myotherimage->getImageBlob(); // I want that the echo of this variable REPLACE the current outbut buffer ( the readfile )
?>
```

There is any way for do this?
I have tried with the ob_* PHP functions, but it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do that.

when you set `header` to `content-type: image/jpeg` means tell browser

> I will send you an image data as a flow

Notice that it is an image **not**  many images.

If you want to show images, you should use `HTML` `<img>` tag.

```
<img src="path/to/image-one"/>
<img src="path/to/image-two"/>
```